# Is there a way I can put all of my view controller date picker logic into a separate class to keep my code organized?

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I'm setting up a very simple iPhone app which has multiple text fields, which use date picker controls to enter date and time strings.

The problem is, while everything is working perfectly, I'm finding that I'm duplicating a lot of code for multiple fields, which feels like bad practice.

What I would like is a way to condense this code into a separate class, and simply call it from anywhere when I need it.

---

Below is an example of what I have in my view controller that works very well, but would have to be duplicated many times for multiple fields:

```
@IBOutlet weak var dateField: UITextField!

@objc func dateFieldModified(sender:UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    dateField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
}

@IBAction func dateFieldModify(_ sender: UITextField) {
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePicker.Mode.date
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.dateFieldModified(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
    dateField.inputView = datePicker
}
```

To summarize, when a user enters the text field "dateField", a date picker pops up and allows the user to scroll and select a date. When a user chooses a date, the text field is set to reflect the selected date.

What I'd like to be able to do in my view controller is do something like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var dateField: UITextField!

@IBAction func dateFieldModify(_ sender: UITextField) {
    let datePicker = DatePicker(field:dateField, mode:"date", format: "MM/dd/yyyy")
    datePicker.loadDatePicker()
}
```

And have a class that is separately defined that maybe looks something like this:

```
class DatePicker {

    var field:UITextField
    var mode:String
    var format:String

    init(field:UITextField, mode:String, format:String) {
        self.field = field
        self.mode = mode
        self.format = format
    }

    @objc func dateFieldModified(sender:UIDatePicker) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        field.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
    }

    func loadDatePicker() {
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePicker.Mode.date
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.dateFieldModified(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
        field.inputView = datePicker
    }

}
```

Implementing the new DatePicker class I wrote above, almost everything works: when I click on the "dateField" text field, the date picker opens up and I'm able to scroll and select a date. However, after selecting a date... the dateField remains empty.

I'm new to Swift and OOP generally, so I'm certain that there is code or an important concept that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can (and probably should) encapsulate this logic in a separate class. But Like OOPer said, you probably want to define a `UITextField` subclass for this.

I’d make a few other suggestions:

1. I’d suggest you give this text field a `date` property, so that you can set and retrieve the `Date` associated with that text field. Just like `UIDatePicker`, the view controller should be interacting with this new control via a `date` property and not have to deal with date formatters itself.
2. When using date picker as the input source, I think it’s good to add a toolbar with a “done” button so the user has a way of dismissing the input source (just like you can with a keyboard that pops up.
3. I wouldn’t suggest using `dateFormat` with the `DateFormatter`, but rather `dateStyle` and `timeStyle`. You always want your user interface to show localized date strings.
4. You should probably handle hardware keyboards that might be hooked up to the device (esp important if targeting iPad). So you might want your date text field to understand the modification of the string directly in the text field as well as picking dates from a date picker.
5. You probably want your own protocol for the text field to tell the UI of changes in the date value.

Thus, I might suggest something like:

```
/// Date text field delegate protocol

@objc protocol DateTextFieldDelegate {
    @objc optional
    func dateTextField(_ dateTextField: DateTextField, didChangeDate: Date?)

    @objc optional
    func didTapDone(dateTextField: DateTextField)
}

/// Date text field
///
/// Used for entry of dates in UITextField, replacing keyboard with date picker.

class DateTextField: UITextField {

    /// `DateTextField` delegate
    ///
    /// You don't need to supply a delegate, but if you do, this will tell you as
    /// the user changes the date.

    weak var dateTextFieldDelegate: DateTextFieldDelegate?

    /// Default date
    ///
    /// If `nil`, uses today's date

    var defaultDate: Date?

    /// Date formatter for date
    ///
    /// Feel free to change `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` to suit the needs of your app.

    let formatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .medium
        formatter.timeStyle = .none
        return formatter
    }()

    /// Date
    ///
    /// The user's selected date.

    var date: Date? {
        didSet {
            dateTextFieldDelegate?.dateTextField?(self, didChangeDate: date)
            if !isManuallyEditing {
                text = date.map { formatter.string(from: $0) }
            }
            datePicker.date = date ?? defaultDate ?? Date()
        }
    }

    var dateTextFieldButtonType: DateTextFieldButtonType = .done {
        didSet { doneButton?.title = dateTextFieldButtonType.buttonText }
    }

    /// The date picker.

    lazy var datePicker: UIDatePicker = {
        let picker = UIDatePicker()
        picker.datePickerMode = .date
        return picker
    }()

    // MARK: - Private properties

    /// Private reference for "Done" button

    private var doneButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    /// Private flag is the user is manually changing the date.

    private var isManuallyEditing = false

    // MARK: - Initialization

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configure()
    }
}

// MARK: - Private utility methods

private extension DateTextField {
    func configure() {
        inputView = datePicker
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerModified(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.barStyle = .default
        toolBar.isTranslucent = true

        let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: dateTextFieldButtonType.buttonText, style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(didTapDone(_:)))

        clearButtonMode = .whileEditing

        toolBar.setItems([space, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        inputAccessoryView = toolBar

        addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldModified(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    }
}

// MARK: - Actions

extension DateTextField {
    @objc func didTapDone(_ sender: Any) {
        if dateTextFieldButtonType == .select {
            date = datePicker.date
        }

        resignFirstResponder()

        dateTextFieldDelegate?.didTapDone?(dateTextField: self)
    }

    @objc func textFieldModified(_ textField: UITextField) {
        isManuallyEditing = true
        date = text.flatMap { formatter.date(from: $0) }
        isManuallyEditing = false
    }

    @objc func datePickerModified(_ datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
        date = datePicker.date
    }
}

// MARK: - Enumerations

extension DateTextField {
    enum DateTextFieldButtonType {
        case select
        case done
        case next
    }
}

extension DateTextField.DateTextFieldButtonType {
    var buttonText: String {
        switch self {
        case .select: return NSLocalizedString("Select", comment: "DateTextFieldButtonType")
        case .done:   return NSLocalizedString("Done",   comment: "DateTextFieldButtonType")
        case .next:   return NSLocalizedString("Next",   comment: "DateTextFieldButtonType")
        }
    }
}
```

You can then specify a base class of `DateTextField` instead of `UITextField` in IB, and you’re done.

Or, if you want to implement the delegate protocol, you can do something like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: DateTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textField.dateTextFieldDelegate = self
    }

}

extension ViewController: DateTextFieldDelegate {
    func didTapDone(dateTextField: DateTextField) {
        print("keyboard dismissed")
    }

    func dateTextField(_ dateTextField: DateTextField, didChangeDate date: Date?) {
        print(date ?? "No date specified")
    }
}
```

Or if you want to have date and time:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: DateTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textField.datePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
        textField.formatter.dateStyle = .full
        textField.formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    }

}
```

Clearly, you can modify this behavior however you want, but it illustrates the idea.

But you are correct that you should abstract this text field with date picker out of your view controller and put it within its own class. And tailor this subclass with whatever behavior you think best suits your app.

Comment: Thank you for your very good and comprehensive response! I'll give your implementation a go and see if I can understand what's going on. I noticed all of your comments in the code, thank you for that as well. It can be tough for a new student to wrap their head around this stuff sometimes.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you for your solution! All I had to do was tie the field object in the storyboard to this class you created, and create the IBOutlet in my view controller. I have to make a time formatted version of this field, but with your solution I think I have a couple of ideas on how to do that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

It is a little bit annoying to manage two instances of separate classes (`UITextField` and your `DatePicker`), and may easily cause reference cycles.

How about defining your own TextField type?

Something like this:

```
class DatePickerTextField: UITextField {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUp()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setUp()
    }

    private func setUp() {
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dateFieldModify(_:)), for: .editingDidBegin)
    }

    @objc func dateFieldModified(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
        self.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
    }

    @IBAction func dateFieldModify(_ sender: UITextField) {
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.dateFieldModified), for: .valueChanged)
        self.inputView = datePicker
    }

}
```

I think you can improve this yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your very quick and kind response. This definitely sounds like the kind of elegant solution I was looking for. However, I'm a little uncertain how to reference this class? Could you please clarify how one might use this class in a view controller to achieve the desired behavior? Thanks again.

Comment: @WarrenO'Brien, that depends on how you use `UITextField`. You put `UITextField` in the storyboard editor?